# Used boot camp for windows - cannot select partition at boot up

Tags: bootcamp, startup, dual-boot

I'm used boot camp and created a partition for windows. It gave the usual directions to insert windows CD. I did that and follows the installation instructions. When windows started up I inserted the OSX Leopard disk to install the drivers.

Now I cannot restart to OSX. It automatically starts to windows every time. I cannot hold down option and choose the partition. I didn't overwrite the OSX partition. It shows up when I click on "My Computer". Whats going on? Did I accidentally overwrite the OSX boot loader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe once you install Boot Camp, the computer will boot into Windows by default unless you change it. Presumably, you're holding down the <kbd>option</kbd> key immediately on startup, it should be pressed as you hear the startup chime?

Apart from holding down the <kbd>option</kbd> key at startup, if you find you can only boot into Windows, this [Apple support page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1310) tells you how you can change the default startup volume from Control Panel.

> This startup volume selection is temporary.  To set the default startup volume for your Mac after your computer is running, open System Preferences and choose Startup Disk from the View menu (in Mac OS X) or open the Boot Camp control panel (in Windows).

Also, do any of the other [Startup key combinations](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533) work, e.g. Safe Boot or Single User Mode?